# ngrep Headers/Frames

Tags: linux, networking, mac-osx, posix

Using the -x flag with ngrep causes the data portion of packets to be displayed in hex. Is there a way to also display the frames/headers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `ngrep` does not show/search within the packets headers. From `man ngrep`, you can read from `ngrep` description:

```
ngrep is a pcap-aware tool that will  allow  you to  specify
extended  regular  expressions to match against data payloads of packets.
```

I could not find any option to show the headers. It would be better to use `tcpdump` if you want more details like headers.